# Add files as read-only to project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the following problem: I need to create a VS project (database project) and I want to make it deployable. To do that I need to add a single SQL function, which belongs to a pool of global functions, to the project. If I now deploy the project, I have all the files that I need.

Problem: I don't want anyone to change the global function inside of my project, so I would like to set it to readonly (not the file itself on the filesystem, it's checked in tfs anyway), so that the file can be deployed, but no one can change it inside the project (at least not by accident).

**Is it possible to add a file as read-only to a VS2010 project?**

Comment: You found any solution ?

Comment: @xmenW.K. - No, never found a solution. Guess I used some kind of workaround or just lived with it. Can't really remember.